Form sections with context menues: How to avoid tabbing trough menu before jumping to a new section - without compromising accessibility
I have a form like the one in the image below, that is divided into multiple sections (the white boxes). Each section has a context menu (marked in red). When you use the tab-key to navigate through the form, tab order will follow the blue line; go through the fields of each section and then trough the buttons in the context menu of that section, before jumping to the first field of the next section.
Does anyone have a good idea on how to make the tab order follow the green line (i.e. skip the contextmenus) by default, WITHOUT compromising accessibility of the context menu, by e.g. setting the tabindex='-1' on the buttons in the menu?

Some example markup:
<form>
  <h1>Checklist</h1>
  <h2>Checklist section</h2>
  <section>
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="firstname">First name</label>
      <input id="firstname" type="text"/>
      <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
      <input id="lastname" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <ul role="menu">
      <li>
        <button role="menuitem">Add note</button>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <button role="menuitem">Add media</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Contact information</h3>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="ContactInfoPhone">Phone</label>
      <input id="ContactInfoPhone" type="tel"/>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="lastname" type="email"/>
    </div>
    <ul role="menu">
      <li>
        <button role="menuitem">Add note</button>
      </li>
      <li> 
        <button role="menuitem">Add media</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</form>

Maybe a solution where you can press a keyboard shortcut to jump to the menu - but how then can it be communicated to the user what keys to use? Or maybe a completely different approach. All ideas welcome :)

Could you post some HTML code please ? I'm blind, so I can't see your picture. More generally, you will get much better and much more precise answers if you show your code. Thank you.

It doesn't seem like it should be desirable to circumvent the current tab order. The current tab order seems appropriate and not overly cumbersome. Anything you do to alter it would create unnecessarily divergent experiences between sighted users relying on pointing devices and other users, which isn't the goal of accessibility.

I agree. Nevertheless, you could group those buttons so that they represent a single tab stop, and manage focus, i.e. allow navigation with arrow keys to pick a button. The … button already hints to a menu structure, which should manage focus anyway. Is this the case? Otherwise, they look a lot like a toolbar. By using the appropriate ARIA roles would be the answer to “how then can it be communicated […] what keys to use”.

Yet, I’m wondering about the order. Wouldn’t these buttons be more appropriate at the beginning of the section (a <fieldset>, I hope?) right after the legend?

@QuentinC Sorry, for not adding and accessible version of my question. Here's some simple markup: https://codepen.io/clausstadel/pen/xxNLNYG Agreed with @Andy That the section's should maybe be fieldset's instead. I'll also have a look at using role toolbar and some focus management, that seem like a good approach.

@ClausStadel Please edit your question to include that code in the question itself using a Stack Snippet instead of linking to a CodePen in a comment. Stack Overflow is meant to be an evergreen resource of helpful questions and answers, and CodePen links go dead over time.
